# Javascript/Jquery window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page the has some data in tabs, Im trying to write a function so that when links are click from another page can load the page with the tabs on and show the correct tab. This is working with the code below, minus the actual changing tabs function. But for some reason using the window.location..... as a variable still scroll the page down to the matching id. Is there another way to get the string in the url after the #. Or can i do it this way but not have to jump to the id? thanks

```
function loadTab(){

var linkToTab = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var linkClass = '.'+linkToTab

if(window.location.hash != '') {

        changeTabs(linkClass);
    }else{
        $('.companyLink:first').addClass('active');
        $('.companyBio:first').addClass('active');
        $('.companyBio:first').fadeIn();

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash character is for anchors.

Use a question mark instead of a hash.

```
<a href="index.html?tabname">
```

and

```
var linkToTab = window.location.search.substr(1);
var linkClass = '.'+linkToTab

if(window.location.search != '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#` part of the URL is traditionally used for anchors. The 'jumping' you see is the original feature.

Modern websites and web-applications use it build a history as [HTML5's history feature isn't widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=history).

To avoid the jumping add `event.preventDefault` to your links, like:

```
<a href="#tab1" id="tab1handle">Tab1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("tab1handle").onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```

You can also make sure the anchor is not defined. In this case the browser will jump to the top of the page. It's up to you whether this is undesirable or not.